# Solving Linear Simultaneous Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of Linear Simultaneous Equations with n variables.
I have solved the equations for particular values of co-efficients of variables & R.H.S. values.
Now I am maintaining the co-efficients of variables same & just changing the R.H.S. values.
So is there a method of computing the solution of this set of equations from the solution of previous set of equations?

In short,
$E_1$: $[A][X] = [B]$
Now equations are solved & solution set $[X]$ is computed.
$E_2$: $[A][X] = [C]$
Now how do I compute new solution set $[X]$ using previous solution set?
If there is a method to do this quickly compared to again solving the equations then it will be very beneficial to me.
Thank You.

Comment: If you had found the inverse of A, while calculating X, then you can directly use it in the next case as well.

Comment: sorry but I am calculating by matrix reduction method (Gauss-Jordan) which does not require inverse of matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to solve $A \, x = b$ with Gauss-Jordan, you can directly solve for both right-hand sides instead. That is, you do Gauss-Jordan with $(a \, b)$ (that is the matrix with the two columns $a$ and $b$) on the right-hand side and perform the usual steps.

Btw: Similarly, you could solve for $A \, X = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then, you end with $X = A^{-1}$.

Comment: oops that was stupid of me to not realise that.
Thanks for reminding me :)